# Set JavaFX TableView Item on Mouse click

Tags: javafx, mouseevent, tableview

I have a JavaFX TableView that is populated by a 2D observable list `ObservableList<ObservableList<Item>>`. I want the user to be able to select an item, and then set that item in the TableView using a mouse click.

Here is the code I have:

```
@Override 
protected void updateItem(Item item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    //Various code to set up the custom CellFactory has been removed.

    this.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
        Item newItem = getNewItem();
        if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY && newItem != null) {
            // Code to set the underlying data item to the new item
        }
    });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You presumably have access to the column index? I.e. this code is in a `TableCell<ObservableList<Item>, Item>` and the current item is at some index in the `ObservableList<Item>`. That index is accessible?

Comment: That index is accessible. I am not sure how to pull the index data from the TableCell to access the index in the `ObservableList<Item>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a

```
TableView<ObservableList<Item>> table ;
```

and a bunch of

```
TableColumn<ObservableList<Item>, Item> col ;
```

each of which has a cell factory which is aware of the `columnIndex`, with the value displayed by the cell given by the `columnIndex`th element of the list representing the row.

Then you can do

```
this.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
    Item newItem = getNewItem();
    if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY && newItem != null) {
        // Code to set the underlying data item to the new item
        ObservableList<Item> row = (ObservableList<Item>) getTableRow().getItem();
        row.set(columnIndex, newItem);
    }
});
```

Comment: It works, although I am now getting a nullPointerError within my custom cell factory, even though the table seems to be updating correctly.

Comment: Figure out what's null : you probably just need to wrap some of the code in an `if (... != null)`

Comment: The null Pointer was being caused by me attempting to refresh the TableView, as the item isn't automatically updating. Now to figure out how to get it to refresh. I suspect that having my data wrapped in an observable list is somehow causing a problem.

Comment: If the table isn't automatically updating, you have something structurally wrong. That's a different question though.